# Refreshing UIWebView causes it to jump up 64 pixels in the y axis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a UIWebView controller that is set up in storyboard and is pushed as a detail controller fron my navigation controller. The UIWebView appears the way I want, perfectly underneath the translucent navigation bar, however when you refresh the UIWebView, it jumps up 64 pixels every time, eventually returning to the top of the web page if you hit refresh enough times.

I already know this is caused by the UIWebView scrollview inset to be set automatically by the storyboard, but I want to leave that be as I like having the UIWebView's content flow underneath the translucent navigation bar.

Is there a way I can fix this 64 pixel jump up every time without the user seeing it happen? Basically when the user taps refresh, it should refresh to that position of the page and not 'jump' anymore.

I appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this in my viewDidLoad:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint lastScroll;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;

    self.lastScroll = CGPointMake(0, -64);
}
```

And in these methods I do this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   self.lastScroll = CGPointMake(self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.lastScroll = CGPointMake(self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x, -64);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.lastScroll = CGPointMake(self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (decelerate != YES)
    {
        self.lastScroll = CGPointMake(self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    }
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked || navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted)
    {
        self.lastScroll = CGPointMake(0, -64);
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    self.navigationItem.title = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];

    [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:self.lastScroll];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set iOS 6/7 Delta Y Parameter to +64 ( if you're building your app in iOS 6 view ) or -64 ( if you have chosen iOS 7 ) :)

Comment: I'm not seeing the Delta Y parameter in storyboard

Comment: Select your element in your storyboard. Then set the Delta Y parameter. It is located in the Size Inspector in the right sidebar. A little downer than where you set your object's width, height and position :)

Comment: Scroll down a bit more and you will see it. If you still don't see it, it's because you have checked "Use AutoLayout" checkbox. : http://s10.postimg.org/j0ry27f3d/Screen_Shot_2014_02_10_at_10_11_31_PM.png

Comment: I have autolayout in my whole app

Comment: Okay, then you cannot fix that 64 pixels manually.
You should use the menubar : Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issue -> Update all constraints in ... ! ( U can check your constraints and add or remove them as they lead to fixing that issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47187/discussion-between-troop231-and-unkn0wn-bit)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your UIWebView controller

```
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;  // Added
```

Comment: If you read my question you'll see I already mentioned this is set in storyboard already. Plus, see my below answer.

Comment: Do you check "Under Top Bars"?